# AffiliateWP + WooCommerce - Need Method of Pulling Nickname from ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, this one has my head in for a loop. I've contacted the Support of the plugin and they basically told me I'm SOL, but I refuse to believe there isn't a way to do this.

I'm using [AffiliateWP](https://github.com/AffiliateWP/AffiliateWP) to attribute sales to a single location. Each Affiliate feeds off of a Wordpress User, and for their nickname I've used their address/location.
Unfortunately, the plugin doesn't include this in the Order Details screen or Order Emails, which is a BIG problem. I've frankensteined some code together but keep getting all kinds of undefined errors because they do everything inside classes, which I guess makes sure that people like me can't fiddle in there?

Function for assigning an affiliate to an order: https://github.com/AffiliateWP/AffiliateWP/blob/master/includes/integrations/class-woocommerce.php#L78

Function for retrieving the Affiliates User ID: https://github.com/AffiliateWP/AffiliateWP/blob/master/includes/affiliate-functions.php#L204

Function for retrieving the Affiliates Name: https://github.com/AffiliateWP/AffiliateWP/blob/master/includes/affiliate-functions.php#L132

[Edit] And finally, my Frankenstein:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
global $Affiliate_WP_WooCommerce;
echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field').':</strong> ' . affiliate_wp()->affiliates->get_affiliate_name( $affiliate_id ) . '</p>';
}
```

This doesn't throw me an error, but it does throw me a blank area...

Comment: Tip #1: Learn to read, and try to understand, error messages.  If you read it, it says `get_affiliate_id` is **not a function** (aka method) on the `$woocommerce` class.  Which begs the question: if AffiliateWP is the plugin for all of the affiliate tracking and info, then why are you trying to access `get_affiliate_id` on the `$woocommerce` class?  What you need to find is _how to get affiliate information_ from an order, using the AffiliateWP code.... (and no, the functions aren't in classes to make it hard for you.  There's many other practical, useful reasons they are in classes).

Comment: Each referral is associated with a WooCommerce order, so it still wouldn't be necessary to include it? Also after some trial, I have removed the global call for Woo, and I got to a point where there are no errors, but also a blank area...

Comment: Not necessarily.  I'm guessing that AffiliateWP has a function that accepts an order or order ID, and returns the related Affiliate information.  _That_ is where I would be looking (not familiar with AffiliateWP, but am fairly faimiliar with Woocommerce)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
global $Affiliate_WP_WooCommerce;
$order_id       = $order->get_id();
$referrals      = affiliate_wp()->referrals->get_by( 'reference', $order_id);
$affiliate_id   = $referrals->affiliate_id;
echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field').':</strong> ' . affiliate_wp()->affiliates->get_affiliate_name( $affiliate_id ) . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the affwp_get_affiliate_name method returns blank on three conditions:

```
if ( ! $affiliate = affwp_get_affiliate( $affiliate ) ) {
    return '';
}
if ( ! $user_info = get_userdata( $affiliate->user_id ) ) {
    return '';
}

...

// If neither are set, return an empty string.
if ( empty( $first_name ) && empty( $last_name ) ) {
    return '';
}
```

Start by manually passing an affiliate id you know to be associated with a record that contains a $first_name and/or $last_name, for example:

`echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field').':</strong> ' . affiliate_wp()->affiliates->get_affiliate_name(5) . '</p>';`

This will rule out if the problem is with the $affiliate_id that you're currently passing it. If you get values returned, it should be a simple matter to fix.

After trying that I would experiment with changing the priority of the add_action(), raising it to 999 or something because it could possibly be executing before the relevant hooks in the plugin.